# .gradle file makes .htaccess ignore a rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have an interesting issue (at least for me). My .htaccess file or apache is not doing what I expect it to do.

I have a bunch of basic rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html?/$1 [L]
```

Overall they work just fine. The problem occurs when in my root a file with same name as "baseurl/NAME" exists. Instead of doing the redirect apache tries to access that file. (`http://base/NAME/foo/bar` tries to access `NAME.gradle` instead of `http://base/index.html?/NAME/foo/bar`)

I know, I know... My first condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` specifies, that the rewrite rule should not be used when a valid file with such name exists. So, I added a specific rule to ignore this for my file NAME.gradle. It didn't work. Threfore I tried to to delete the "file check" condition altogether. And it did not work again. That is when I started to experiment.

---

And here comes the fun part. Let's say my URL is `http://base/NAME/foo/bar`.

I reduce the rewrite rules/conditions to single: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html?/$1 [L]`

Having file **NAME.txt** works as expected. URL rewritten and everything working.

Having file **NAME.php** also works as expected.

Basicly having file **NAME.any_random_suffix** (including .html) works as expected.

However **NAME.gradle** file somehow makes apache ignore the rule (or maybe something different happens and the rule is applied - who knows, but I can definitely tell, that index.html is not accessed). Apache tries to acces the NAME.gradle file. That is of course incorrect and unwanted behavior.

---

Now I could just rename the file and all would work right. However I am wondering why this happens at all. To mix the things up even more, out of three colleagues (including me), one experiences this behavior for couple of weeks, the other does not and it works for him as expected. And I wasn't experiencing the behavior until I added a new virtual host. Now even when I remove the virtual host the behavior stays and NAME.gradle file breaks the navigation (and it is not due to the apache restart after adding the new host because on my devel machine apache is restarted daily).

Comment: Enable rewrite logging, and go check what’s going on ...

Comment: @CBroe: The first entry already starts as if the url was `http://base/NAME.gradle/foo/bar`. I tried to bypass it with a rule that strips the ".gradle" part (which I see in a log works, because index.html appears there -> `internal redirect with /index.html [INTERNAL REDIRECT]` ) but to no avail (because in the browser I end up with the wrong file).